# Elasticsearch : Curator does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying out the basic code from curator

http://curator.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/examples.html

and i try

```
import elasticsearch
import curator
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([{'host': "http://localhost", 'port':9200}])

    ilo = curator.IndexList(client)
    ilo.filter_by_regex(kind='prefix', value='logstash-')
    print ilo
```

but i get

```
ilo = curator.IndexList(client)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IndexList'
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your version of curator is not 4.0. Check the documentation of the vesion you are using. For example for 3.5.1: http://curator.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.1/